# Elementary question on continuity and locally square integrability of a function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $\;f\in L^2_{loc}(\mathbb R;\mathbb R^m)\;$. I know that $\; L^2(\mathbb R^n)\;$ is the completion of the continuous functions with respect to the $\;L^2$-norm.

**I'm wondering if this is enough in order to claim that $\;f\;$ is equal almost everywhere to a continuous function.**

From my point of view, since continuous functions are dense in $\;L^2\;$, there must be a sequence of continuous functions converging to a square integrable one.But I'm not very sure if this implies the above.

I 've been stuck to this so any help would be valuable. I apologize in advance if my question is quite silly.

Thanks

Comment: What would be the continuous function $f$ such that $g(x)=\begin{cases}\lvert x\rvert^{-1/4}&\text{if }-1<x<1\wedge x\ne 0\\ 0&\text{if }x\le-1\vee x\ge1\vee x=0\end{cases}$ is equal to $f$ amost everywhere?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli you probably want to multiply that with an indicator function.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Ah right, I missed the local bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I know that $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ is the completion of the continuous functions with respect to the $L^2$-norm." Not all continuous functions! You need continuous functions subject to some kind of growth condition. A favorite here is the space of continuous functions with compact support.

"I'm wondering if this is enough in order to claim that $\;f\;$ is equal almost everywhere to a continuous function." No, that is far far away from being true. Consider $f= \chi_{[0,1]}$ for example.

Comment: The characteristic function of the unit interval is continuous almost everywhere. What one should show is that there is an L^2 function such that every representant has a non-zero set of non-continuous points. An example would be the charcteristic function of Cantors set.

Comment: @PeterWildemann $\,$ Continuous a.e. and a.e. equal to a continuous function are different things. The OP was wondering about the latter.

Comment: You are completely right! Excuse me.